# Resolving local hostnames with D-Link DIR-657 router

Tags: router, dns

How can I resolve local hostnames with the D-Link DIR-657 router?

With my old router I could just enter the device name followed by `.home`, eg. `raspberrypi.home`.

However neither of these seems to work:

- `raspberrypi`
- `raspberrypi.home`
- `raspberrypi.local`
- `raspberrypi.dlinkrouter`

The router resolves `dlinkrouter` to the IP-address of the router.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling NetBIOS to allow devices in network discover each other:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to set a DHCP reservation for each device. The router should then resolve those names for other clients on your network (provided that your hosts use the router for resovling DNS, which they should by default).

To do this, go to the **Network Setup** page, under the **Setup** tab on the DIR-567's admin page. Look for the section towards the bottom labelled *Add DHCP Reservation*.

Enter:

- The hostname (*i.e.* `raspberrypi`) under *Computer Name*
- An IP address that falls within the *DHCP IP Address Range* in the *DHCP Server Settings* section above
- The MAC address of the device (findable via `ifconfig` on Unixes, or `ipconfig /all` on Windows)

Check the *enable* box, then click save. Repeat this for each machine you want to assign a hostname to.

Comment: This doesn't work for me! I have rebooted the router and confirmed the raspberry pi is on the correct ip-address. Screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/gGQVY.png http://i.imgur.com/3eU5g.png

Comment: Check what DNS servers your other clients are using. If they're set to use external servers (i.e. not `192.168.0.1`), then your router can't resolve hostnames for them.

Comment: I haven't set any external DNS servers and going to `http://dlinkrouter/` works. `nslookup` returns this for `dlinkrouter`: `Name: dlinkrouter.profibernet.dk
Address: 192.168.0.1`

Comment: Hmm, in that case, all I can suggest is trying a restart of your client to flush the DHCP and DNS information. But it's possible that D-Link routers don't use the entered hostname information for DNS resolution, in which case you can either go with a third party firmware, manually edit the hosts file, or set up an internal DNS server.